# need to space bars apart on python graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have three years of data that I am plotting into a bar graph.
How do I separate the bars, space them apart, so that they are not overlapping?
I am struggling using the ax ticks.
New to python.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


success2019 = np.array([30.3,42.3,34.1,36.1,30.5,28,32,51.9])
units2019 = np.array([30,'30A',37,'37A',49,50,51,58])

success2018 = np.array([30.4,34.4,43,47.5])
units2018 = np.array([46,30,'68A','30A'])

success2017 = np.array([33.2,29.1,22,62.2,22.3,36.9])
units2017 = np.array([72,74,78,'30A','32A','37A'])

pltone = plt.bar(units2019, success2019, color = 'blue', label = '2019')
plttwo = plt.bar(units2018, success2018, color = 'purple', label = '2018')
pltthree = plt.bar(units2017, success2017, color = 'green',label = '2017')

ax19 = plt.subplot()
ax19.set_xticks(range(len(success2019)))
ax19.set_xticklabels(units2019)

ax18 = plt.subplot()
ax18.set_xticks(range(len(success2018)))
ax18.set_xticklabels(units2018)

ax17 = plt.subplot()
ax17.set_xticks(range(len(success2017)))
ax17.set_xticklabels(units2017)


plt.title('Hunt unit vs Success Rates 2017-2019')
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.ylabel('Success Rate %')
plt.xlabel('Hunting Units')
plt.legend (['2019', '2018', '2017'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks OK for me: All bars are separated by spaces and they are automatically ordered.

[image: original output]

However, if you like to create separate subplots, use this snippet:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3)
axs[0].bar(units2019, success2019, color = 'blue', label = '2019')
axs[1].bar(units2018, success2018, color = 'purple', label = '2018')
axs[2].bar(units2017, success2017, color = 'green',label = '2017')
```

[image: output 3 subplots]

If you want to place them in groups next to each other in a single axis, go with:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# create new x-axis points
x2017 = np.linspace(0,len(units2017)-1,len(units2017))
# plot
ax.bar(x2017, success2017, color = 'green',label = '2017')

x2018 = np.linspace(0,len(units2018)-1,len(units2018)) + x2017[-1]+1
ax.bar(x2018, success2018, color = 'purple', label = '2018')

x2019 = np.linspace(0,len(units2019)-1,len(units2019)) + x2018[-1]+1
ax.bar(x2019, success2019, color = 'blue', label = '2019')

# set ticks + labels
ax.set_xticks( np.concatenate((x2017,x2018,x2019)) )
ax.set_xticklabels( np.concatenate((units2017,units2018,units2019)) )
```

[image: grouped plot]

You have full control over the *width* of the bars with the optional argument `width=`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x2017 = np.linspace(0,len(units2017)-1,len(units2017))
ax.bar(x2017, success2017, color = 'green',label = '2017', width=1)

x2018 = np.linspace(0,len(units2018)-1,len(units2018)) + x2017[-1]+1
ax.bar(x2018, success2018, color = 'purple', label = '2018') # default width=0.8

x2019 = np.linspace(0,len(units2019)-1,len(units2019)) + x2018[-1]+1
ax.bar(x2019, success2019, color = 'blue', label = '2019', width = 0.4)

ax.set_xticks( np.concatenate((x2017,x2018,x2019)) )
ax.set_xticklabels( np.concatenate((units2017,units2018,units2019)) )
```

[image: width]

Answer (score 0):

Combine the data by year and then use a pivot to transform the columns into yearly data. Create a bar chart with a pandas plot of that transformed data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

success2019 = np.array([30.3,42.3,34.1,36.1,30.5,28,32,51.9])
units2019 = np.array([30,'30A',37,'37A',49,50,51,58])

success2018 = np.array([30.4,34.4,43,47.5])
units2018 = np.array([46,30,'68A','30A'])

success2017 = np.array([33.2,29.1,22,62.2,22.3,36.9])
units2017 = np.array([72,74,78,'30A','32A','37A'])

df19 = pd.DataFrame({'index':units2019,'year':[2019]*len(success2019),'success':success2019})
df18 = pd.DataFrame({'index':units2018,'year':[2018]*len(success2018),'success':success2018})
df17 = pd.DataFrame({'index':units2017,'year':[2017]*len(success2017),'success':success2017})

ax = dfs.pivot('index', 'year','success').plot.bar()
ax.set_title('Hunt unit vs Success Rates 2017-2019')
ax.set_ylabel('Success Rate %')
ax.set_xlabel('Hunting Units')
```

[image]